Как в dearpygui изменять возможные значения combo?
делаю проект с gui на dearpygui. У меня возник вопрос: как можно изменить значения combo(выпадающего списка)? = мне нужна функция по принципу set_value(), но для combo. В официальной документации я не нашёл упоминаний о такой функции. Если оно там есть, то я буду очень признателен, если вы меня "ткнёте носом").

Если требуется изменять значения combo после его создания, то должен подойти configure_item
dpg.configure_item("my_combo", items=[...])

